# How to sort a array with objects foreign key value must be first (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort an array of objects in Laravel, I set my current foreign key value of my post `categorie_id` to come first in the array.

After that, the other objects need to be filtered in desc order.

**Code:**

```
$categorie = Categorie::all()->sortBy($posts->categorie_id);
```

This does not quite work the array stays the same.
In this case, my VIEW has a post with a foreign key of 4

[image]

Comment: Not clear about what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
$categorie = Categorie::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('categorie_id', 'desc');
}])->find($categorie_id);

// when lazy loading
$categorie = Categorie::find($categorie_id);
$categorie->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('categorie_id', 'desc');
}]);

// or on the collection
$categorie = Categorie::find($categorie_id);
$categorie->posts->sortByDesc('categorie_id');


// or querying students directly
$categorie = Categorie::whereHas('posts', function ($q) use ($categorie_id) {
  $q->where('id', $categorie_id);
})->orderBy('categorie_id')->get();
```

Comment: This gives me:asort() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given

Comment: categorie_id comes from the table "posts", the table posts does not know this

Comment: @SebastianTramper so categorie has many post, and u want to sort category by post's categorie_id?